# VJP and JVP in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, implementation

It is possible to obtain the vector-Jacobian product in Tensorflow through the `output_gradients` keyword arg in the `gradient` function. You can set the value of `output_gradients` to the vector in the vector-Jacobian product, like the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:  
x  = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])  
tape.watch(x)  
y = x*x 

vec = tf.constant([2.0, 3.0, 4.0]) # vector of the vector-Jacobian product

grads = tape.gradient(y,x,output_gradients = vec)
print(grads) # prints the vector-Jacobian product, [4.,12.,36.]
```

My question is how I can evaluate the Jacobian-vector product on Tensorflow. I know this product does not appear in backpropagation but in forwardpropagation. However, I need to evaluate the product of a custom vector by the Jacobian without computing it explicitly. Should I use [tf.autodiff.ForwardAccumulator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autodiff/ForwardAccumulator) instead? Thanks in advance.